# Include library from data directory in main.js in Firefox add-on

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In my Firefox add-on using the Add-on SDK, I'm trying to include two library files from the `data` directory in `main.js`, and it's not working.

I have the following directory structure:

```
data
-- jquery-latest.min.js
-- pagemodscript.js
-- mylibrary.js

lib
-- main.js
```

`pagemodscript.js` uses jQuery, and that works (using `contentScriptFile`).

I also want to use jQuery and `mylibrary.js` in `main.js`, but that's not working.

Various things I've tried result in error messages "ReferenceError: [class in mylibrary.js] is not defined", "ModuleNotFoundError: unable to satisfy: require(mylibrary.js)", and "has no authority to load".

I tried moving `mylibrary.js` and copying `jquery-latest.min.js` to `lib`, but that resulted in one of those error messages.

What's the best way to set this up?

Note: the reason I want to use jQuery in `main.js` is because - after an event generated by `pagemodscript.js` - I want `main.js` to add a div to the current page in which it will display a list of objects it created from another event generated by `pagemodscript.js`. Is the better practice to have `pagemodscript.js` create those objects and create the div? In that case, this would work: I'd load `mylibrary.js` into `pagemodscript.js` using `contentScriptFile`. In that case, `pagemodscript.js` would be creating objects of the class defined in `mylibrary.js`, and that doesn't seem as good a design as the way I'd prefer to do things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also want to use jQuery and `mylibrary.js` in `main.js`

That won't do you any good. jQuery expects to run in a window and works with the DOM. Extension files execute in an entirely different environment - there is no window to access and some typical window functions are unavailable. Also, extension files simply aren't allowed to access the DOM, all web page access has to happen in content scripts.

> I want `main.js` to add a div to the current page

You should send a message to your content script (`pagemodscript.js`) and let it create the div for you. That's how it works with the Add-on SDK.

Comment: After posting this, I carefully read [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/dev-guide/addon-development/web-content.html) and got it working the way you describe.